# Safari gives weird CSS behavior

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, safari, cross-browser, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JQuery's sortable (as grid) to be able to sort divs, the first of which is approximately three times as wide as the rest. I want to display them in just two rows, which Chrome and Firefox have been able to do just fine, but Safari is displaying them sort of like this:

```
BIGDIV
DIV DIV
DIV DIV
DIV DIV
```

By the way I'm doing this in rails which will explain my code below:

```
<ul id="sortable" style= "width: 1050px; height: 625px;" >
<li id="newspod"  style="width: 610px;">
    <div class="pod" style="width:598px;">
        <div id="header" style="width: 598px">NEWS</div>
    </div>
</li>
<% @pods.each do |podli| %>
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="pod">
        <div id="header"><%= podli.name %></div>        
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I removed a little to make it more readable. Also, here's my CSS:

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px; padding: 0;}
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 200px; height: 294px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
.pod {
width:188px;
height:282px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
/********** CSS 3 **********/
box-shadow:3px 3px 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 10px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 10px #000;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: I figured this out, if anyone's interested. There was an open div tag that was screwing me up (not shown above)

Comment: Add your own answer and accept it so this question wouldn't show up as unanswered.